# Arrows within text

Tags: arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I was wondering how to add some arrows inside the text, like in the following picture: 
[image]

I know that there's tikz, but I do not know how to insert this specific kind of arrows. If you could point me to some specific package which could be helpful, I will try to write down some lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrows can be done with Tikz by inserting coordinates in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\putmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(myStop#1);}
\newcommand\drawmyarrows[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \foreach \pos in {#1}{%
      \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- +(0,-0.5) -| (myStop\pos);
    }\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
I don'\putmark{1}t believe [that\putmark{2} he wants me [to \putmark{3}think [that he didn'\drawmyarrows{1,2,3}t (do) it.]]]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution has some limitations. The text arrow has to be in one line to like nice, and the space for the arrows are not considered by LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know a good beginner's guide to Tikz?

Comment: Even though the manual can look quite scary with close to 1200 pages, I would recommend it. There is a tutorial in the beginning (Picture for Karl’s Students) that explains things. You can also find a lot of examples online, e.g. at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I was indeed a little bit scared by that bulky manual.